# Chart Y Value Range, Start from and steps I want from 2000,2001,2002...3000

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, range

[image]

Using C# WinForms Chart. I want above chart, I want to set Y Values Range from 2000, 2001,2002...up to 3000.
How we can set a range in Chart and how we can define steps in Y Value Range.

Data Dynamically accessed from SQL Server.

```
private void LineChart()
    { //yet not working, steps are not settings yet
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
        string Date1 = date.ToShortDateString();
        Date1 = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        //Fetch the Statistical data from database.
        string query = "SELECT  *   FROM ( Select TOP 500  
SrNo,Machine,ConeWeight,Date,DateTime FROM [DB_SProd].[dbo]. 
[TableProduction] Where Date='"+Date1+"' order by SrNo DESC ) as 
Machines\r\n  order by SrNo;\r\n ";
        
       
        DataTable dt = dbConn.GetData(query);

        //Get the DISTINCT Countries.
        List<string> Machine1 = (from p in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                  select p.Field<string>("Machine")).ToList();
        List<int> Weight1 = (from p in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                 select p.Field<int>("ConeWeight")).ToList();
        int[] countCones = { };
        //Remove the Default Series.
        if (chart3.Series.Count() == 1)
        {
            chart3.Series.Remove(chart3.Series[0]);
        }

        //Loop through the Countries.
        foreach (string macine in Machine1)
        {

            //get each machine name dynamitcally
            string[] x = (from p in dt.AsEnumerable()
                       where p.Field<string>("Machine") == macine
                       orderby p.Field<string>("Machine") ascending
                       select p.Field<string>("Machine")).ToArray();

            //Get the Total of Orders for each Country.
            int[] y = (from p in dt.AsEnumerable()
                       where p.Field<string>("Machine") == macine
                       orderby p.Field<string>("Machine") ascending
                       select p.Field<int>("ConeWeight")).ToArray();


            countCones = new int[y.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < y.Length; i++)
            {
                countCones[i] = i;
            }

            //Add Series to the Chart.

            if (chart3.Series.IsUniqueName(macine))
            {
                //chart1.Series.Add(macine);

                chart3.Series.Add(new Series(macine));
                chart3.Series[macine].IsValueShownAsLabel = false;
                chart3.Series[macine].BorderWidth = 2;
                chart3.Series[macine].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
                chart3.Series[macine].Points.DataBindXY(countCones,y);
                
                
            }
           
        }

        chart3.Legends[0].Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: _"How we can set a range in Chart"_ - what exactly do you mean by that? Do you want to translate the chart down to have the x-Axis crossing at 2000 instead of 0, so you can increase the displayed resolution?

Comment: What is the type of the chart and what framework is it from? There _may_ be something built-in to "focus" the displayed area.

Comment: its a line chart, I want to keep the Y Axix values from 2000 to 3000, because Weight of cone is only vary between 2000 to 3000, therefore if we start it from 0, we can't determine the real weight of each cone

Comment: I can _see_ that it's a line chart. We need to know the exact Framework/Lib and Type (as in "class").

Comment: We have almost 50 production lines, some lines remain off some in working condition. We collect working lines production in form of Cones and each cone has weight range from 2000 grams to 3000 grams. Data a collected from SQL Server, Lines are added dynamically. other code is mentioned in detail.

Answer (score 1):

Manually:

```
chart3.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 2001;
chart3.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 3000;
```

Or automatically

```
chart3.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsStartedFromZero = false;
chart3.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsMarginVisible = false;
```

And set the steps is by:

```
chart3.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 1;
```

For the new question why is not getting the new data:
Because it is only creating new Series which is not in chart. If you want to update the existing series you can do it like this.

```
        if (chart3.Series.IsUniqueName(macine)) {
            //chart3.ChartAreas.Clear();
            //chart3.ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea1");
            //chart3.Series.Add(new Series(macine));
            chart3.Series.Add(macine);
            chart3.Series[macine].IsValueShownAsLabel = false;
            chart3.Series[macine].BorderWidth = 2;
            chart3.Series[macine].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            //chart3.DataBindings.Clear(); i dont think this is needed

            chart3.Series[macine].Points.DataBindXY(countCones,y);
            
            // chart3.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 2001;
// this can be moved out of the loop it is only need to set it up once <
            chart3.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsStartedFromZero = false; 
            chart3.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsMarginVisible = false;
            chart3.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
// >
            //chart3.Update();
          
            
        }
        else
        {
           
           chart3.Series[macine].Points.DataBindXY(countCones,y);
        }
```

Comment: I am using C# 4.6.2 framework in Winform and there is no property of "AxisY" chart3.Series[macine].AxisY.Minimum = 2001;

Comment: @HassanAkhtar Chart3.ChartAreas not Chart3.Series

Comment: chart1.ChartAreas.Add(macine); //machine has the list of machines producing 
      cones,
                    
                    chart3.ChartAreas[macine].AxisY.Minimum = 2001; 
 Error: System.ArgumentException: 'A chart element with the name 'M1' could not be found in the 'ChartAreaCollection'.'

Comment: @HassanAkhtar Try it with index. like chart3.ChartAreas[index]

Comment: in your case i think it is only one so index should be 0, always

Comment: Can you pls favor, line chart doesn't refresh, data remain same as I have used timer to refresh it after 200ms. But chart remain same doesn't update with new data

Comment: @HassanAkhtar added new answer

Answer (score 0):

```cs
if (chart3.Series.IsUniqueName(macine))
{
    chart3.ChartAreas.Clear();
    chart3.ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea1");
    chart3.Series.Add(new Series(macine));
    chart3.Series[macine].IsValueShownAsLabel = false;
    chart3.Series[macine].BorderWidth = 2;
    chart3.Series[macine].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
    chart3.DataBindings.Clear();
    chart3.Series[macine].Points.DataBindXY(countCones,y);
    
    // chart3.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 2001;
    chart3.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsStartedFromZero = false;
    chart3.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsMarginVisible = false;
    chart3.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
    chart3.Update();
}
```

Main issue resolved, but it doesn't refresh the chart as timer refreshes this function with new data, chart remains the same.

Comment: Before it worked?